# Get and use css property value in css, for calc

Tags: html, css

I wanted to get value of css property to use in the css function `calc()`

For Example if I want to give a total height of `100px` for a component, I have to compensate the top value by subtracting it.

```
.element{
   top:30px;
   width: calc( 100px - get(top) );
}
```

is there a function like `get()` used above, that would let me use a css property value of the class?

I know I can declare an upper variable for top and use it around, but is there a direct means close to this?

Comment: To answer your question with how you phrased it; No. CSS does not offer such programmatical logic. You'd have to resort to a JS solution to apply the logic that you are attempting. With that said, mainly the logic is flawed from the beginning if calc() is needed. calc() is a very edge-case solution in most cases and can often be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using JavaScript, Lucas's answer is correct and can be used to get a CSS property value and then add another property using that value.

While CSS alone does allow any way of retrieving and reusing another core CSS property's value, you can create a CSS custom property and use that for both properties like this:

```css
.element{
   --top: 30px;
   top: var(--top);
   width: calc(100px - var(--top));
}
```

You can name that variable whatever you like as well. it doesn't need to match the property value. This would also work:

```css
.element{
   --my-spacing: 30px;
   top: var(--my-spacing);
   width: calc(100px - var(--my-spacing));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to do that is using Javascript to get the value and set the width of the element through JS. I've never seen nothing that looks like what you want.

Like this below:

```
<script>
  const top = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.element-top')).height
  const element = document.querySelector('.element');
  element.style.height = `calc(100px + ${top})`;
</script>
```